# How to detect change versions of synchronization queries when sql server change tracking used?

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

There are 2 databases with different structure. I want to build queries for merging data from one db to another, using ms sql change tracking. I need two-way synchronization.

So, if I build query by changes and apply it on second database - new changes will be generated on second database. How to detect this changes to not apply it on first database again when I run sync from second database to first?

Comment: How do you avoid inserting duplicates and rewriting local changes with remote?

Comment: Inserting duplicates is impossible, because I "remember" latest applied change tracking item. So, one change cannot be applied twice. To detect that row in destination table modified locally I analyze changes on destination table. If exists changes with primary key which maps to primary key in source table, and version of change greater than version of applied change, conflict situation reported to resolve manually.

Comment: How about adding a new `bit` column which tells you if it has been synchronized before?

Comment: One database is external, so I cannot change structure. May be it possible without changing structure?